# PHP explode work only with last line

Tags: php, explode, http-referer

I have a PHP script that include different pages for special referers:

```
$ref_found = false; 

// get referer if exists 
$referer = false; 
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ) { 
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    // get content of list.txt 
    $list = explode(chr(10), file_get_contents('list.txt')); 
    foreach ( $list as $l ) { 
        if ( strlen($l) > 0 ) { 
            if ( strpos( $referer, $l ) ) { 
                $ref_found = true; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 

// include the correct file 
if ( $ref_found ) { 
    require_once('special_page.html'); 
} else { 
    require_once('regular_page.html'); 
}
```

Referer DB is in simple txt file (list.txt) and it looks like this:

> domain1.com
>
> domain2.com
>
> domain3.com

Unfortunalty this script works only for last domain from the list (domain3.com).

What shoud I add? `\n` ?
Or it's better idea to create domains DB in different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you `explode()` your list of domain names, you end up with  whitespace around each item. At the very least, you will have a newline (`\n`) somewhere, since the linebreaks in your file are probably `\r\n`.

So you're checking against something like `" domain1.com"` or maybe `"\ndomain1.com"`, or maybe `"domain1.com\n"`. Since this extra whitespace doesn't exists in the referrer header, it's not matching when you expect it to.

By calling [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on each value you find, you'll get a clean domain name that you can use to do a more useful comparison:

```
$list = explode("\n", file_get_contents('list.txt'));
foreach ($list as $l) {
    $l =  trim($l);
    if ((strlen($l) > 0) && (strpos($referer, $l) !== false)) {
        $ref_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I made a couple other minor updates to your code as well:

1. I switched away from using `chr()` and just used a string literal (`"\n"`). As long as you use double-quotes, it'll be a literal newline character, instead of an actual `\` and `n`, and the string literal is much easier to understand for somebody reading your code.
2. I switched from a `"\r"` character (chr 10) to a `"\n"` character (chr 13). There's several different newline formats, but the most common are `"\n"` and `"\r\n"`. By exploding on `"\n"`, your code will work with both formats, where `"\r"` will only work with the second.
3. I combined your two `if` statements. This is a very minor update that doesn't have much effect except to (in my opinion) make the code easier to read.
4. I updated your [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to do a literal comparison to false (`!==`). It's probably not an issue with this code because the referrer value will start with `http://`, but it's a good habit to get into. If the substring happens to occur at the beginning of the parent string, `strpos()` will return `0`, which will be interpreted as false in your original code.
5. I added a `break` statement in your loop if you found a matching domain name. Once you find one and set the flag, there's no reason to continue checking the rest of the domains in the list, and `break` allows you to cancel the rest of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @user2545134 If you found this answer useful, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check-mark beside it. Once you have a bit more rep, you'll also be able to upvote any answers that are helpful.

Comment: done,
"break" is awesome, I can set most popular domains at beginning of list to speed up

Answer (score 0):

```
chr(13) == "\n"
chr(10) == "\r"
```

`"\n"` is most likely what you want.

Comment: i know what `\n` is without having to reference a ascii table :)

Comment: OPS problem is OP using just \r,